# RichTextBox bold text

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I am filling a `richtextbox` with information gathered from Textboxes. I need that the input from the user gets Bold in the Richtextbox. I have tried different answers in SO, but or either I am doing something wrong or I couldn't find the right answer to this.

I've tried RTF and appendtext:

```
rtbGeneratedText.Text += @"In answer to your request regarding " + 
    rtbSpecialRequest.Text +
    " for your booking " +
    bookingNumberTxt.Text +
    " the hotel has informed us that unfortunately it is not possible." + "\r\n" + 
    "Please let us know if this negative answer will affect your reservation in any way.";
```

Comment: This shows the text contents of your `richtextbox`, but not how you are attempting to format that text. Can you include some more of your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can **Bold** a portion of the sentence (a few words):

```
string target = "the hotel has informed us that unfortunately it is not possible";
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(target);
RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = target.Length;
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Or if you want to **Bold** all the text:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = RichTextBox1.Length;
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void toolBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Toggles the 'Bold' of the selected text:
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold ?
        new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Regular) :
        new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the end of the RTB, without losing existing formatting, and simply specifying whether it should be bold or not:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbAppendText("In answer to your request regarding ", false);
    rtbAppendText(rtbSpecialRequest.Text, true);
    rtbAppendText(" for your booking ", false);
    rtbAppendText(bookingNumberTxt.Text, true); 
    rtbAppendText(" the hotel has informed us that unfortunately it is not possible.\r\n" +
        "Please let us know if this negative answer will affect your reservation in any way.", false);            
}

private void rtbAppendText(String text, bool bold)
{
    rtbGeneratedText.SelectionStart = rtbGeneratedText.TextLength;
    rtbGeneratedText.SelectionLength = 0;
    rtbGeneratedText.SelectionFont = new Font(rtbGeneratedText.Font, bold ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular);
    rtbGeneratedText.SelectedText = text;
}
```